# Flex 4: use google APIs in RIA without server side code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, google-api

Just to confirm what I think I understand from reading about use of google APIs in RIAs (FLEX 4 and ActionScript) there is no way to connect to blogger API for example, directly from RIA because of google's crossdomain.xml file, right?

So if I want to use their APIs to get some data like content of my mailbox or list of posts on my blog I have to have some code running server side and RIA would just use that code as httpservice to collect data from google?

Or maybe I got it completly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you are right. of course there are dark magic workarounds:

1. embed a signed java applet. if the user accepts the certifficate, it has virtually any permission. bind a port and use it for communication between flash and java (over TCP). be sure to respond to the policy file request, otherwise flash will automatically close the connection.
2. get a DNS server. when user opens a session, generate a subdomain, such as sessionID.yourdomain.tl with an extremely short TTL, that maps to your own server. the first request will be for an additional SWF file, the "proxy". after that request, remap the subdomain to the google server. the flash player is thus tricked into perceiving the proxy and the target API as having the same origin. be sure the proxy allows access from the container and create a little interface that allows you app to issue URL requests through the proxy.

**edit:**

well the first approach is actually feasible: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html . i suppose it is easier to implement a lightweight TCP protocoll between java and flash, but an alternative would be to make flash->java communication HTTP based. Don't know if there are any libraries for handling HTTP requests in java.

as for the second approach, you can use [BIND with DLZ](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/). once you have it up and running, altering the DB should suffice.

none the less having an intermediary server is the safest solution. although you may wanna consider that some of google's APIs are limited per key per day **per IP**. you should check this to avoid problems. a few years ago we ran into this while using Google's APIs for geocoding.

Comment: that's indeed sounds like voodoo in the middle of swamps :) could you throw me some links with info more "for dummies" than for masters on these workarounds? because as for now I think it is easier not to try any voodoo and just go with server side talking to google API

Comment: thx a lot for these links, I will definitely take a look at that black magic workarounds :)